# how to write a file from user input[asm,dos]?

Tags: assembly, dosbox

i want to make a procedure that creates a file when inputing the name of the file in the console,how can i do this? i've tried with those two procedures:

```
filenameStr db 13,0,13 dup("$")
createline db 10,13,"/c/ ","$"
space db " ","$"
filehandle dw 0
```

proc:

```
proc Createfile
mov dx,offset createline
mov ah,9h
int 21h
mov dx,offset space 
mov ah,9h 
int 21h
mov dx,offset filenameStr
mov bx,dx
mov [byte ptr bx],13    ;8+1+3+1
mov ah,0Ah
int 21h
mov dx,offset filenameStr + 2
mov ah,9h
int 21h
mov [byte ptr filenameStr+2+8],0
call OpenFile 
xor  bx,bx
call WipeClean

call CreateFile1
call CloseFile 
call GetCommandLetter
endp CreateFile
```

and:

```
proc CreateFile1
    mov ah,3ch
    mov cx,00000000b
    lea dx,[filenameStr]
    int 21h
    mov [filehandle],ax 
    ret
endp CreateFile1
```

**note:** those procedures are not showed in the code since i've changed the code to my older code without the writing file procedures.

full program is here:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

szMsg1 db "Hi! What do you want to do?",10,13,10,13,"/h-help(see all the commands)",10,13,"/e-Exit",10,13,10,13,"$"
szHelloWorld db 10,13,"Hello World!",10,13,"$"
ErrorMsg db 10,13,"Illegal Command,Try again!",10,13,"$"
filenameStr db 13,0,13 dup("$")
help db 10,13,"HELP LIST:",10,13,"-----------",10,13,"Commands are:",10,13," /e-Exit",10,13," /h-help",10,13," /1-Says: 'Hello World!'",10,13,"$"
filename db ?,0
filehandle dw 0
ErrorOpenMsg db 'Error',10,13,'$'
FileNameLength db "file name consists of 8 letters max! (dont forget to add '.txt' at the end of the name: 'example.txt')",10,13,"/r/ ","$"
fileString db 255 dup (0)
space db " ","$"
CommandMsg db 10,13,"Enter your command:",10,13,"Command: ","$",10,13
filereaderline db "file's text:","$"


CODESEG     
proc WipeClean
     mov  [byte ptr fileString + bx], 0
     inc  bx
     cmp  bx, 255
     jb   WipeClean
endp WipeClean   

proc OpenFile
;Open file
    mov ah,3Dh
    xor al,al
    lea dx,[filenameStr+2]
    int 21h
    jc openerror
    mov [filehandle],ax
    ret
openerror:  
    mov dx,offset ErrorOpenMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    ret
endp OpenFile   

proc ReadFile
    mov ah,3fh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp ReadFile   

proc DeleteFile
    mov ah,41h
    lea dx,[filenameStr+2]
    int 21h
endp DeleteFile

proc DisplayFileString
    mov ah,09h
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h 
endp DisplayFileString  

proc KeyStroke
    xor ax,ax
    int 16h
endp KeyStroke

proc WriteToFile
    mov ah,40h
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    mov cx,255
    lea dx,[fileString]
    int 21h
    ret
endp WriteToFile

proc CloseFile
    mov ah,3Eh
    mov bx,[filehandle]
    int 21h
    ret
endp CloseFile  

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov ah,0
    mov al,2
    int 10h

    mov dx,offset szMsg1
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

_Error:

    mov dx,offset ErrorMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h 

GetCommandLetter:
    mov dx,offset CommandMsg
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bl,al   

    mov ah, 1h
    int 21h
    mov bh,al   
compare:    

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'h'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'H'
    je _help

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'1'
    je PrintLine

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'e'
    je _exit

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp bh,'E'
    je exit


    mov dx,offset space
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset FileNameLength
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'r'
    je GetFileName

    cmp bl,'/'
    jne _Error
    cmp  bh,'R'
    je GetFileName

    jmp _Error
_exit:
    jmp exit

_help:  
    mov dx,offset help
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

GetFileName:
    mov dx,offset space 
    mov ah,9h 
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr
    mov bx,dx
    mov [byte ptr bx],13    ;8+1+3+1
    mov ah,0Ah
    int 21h
    mov dx,offset filenameStr + 2
    mov ah,9h
    int 21h
    mov [byte ptr filenameStr+2+8],0
    call OpenFile 
    xor  bx,bx
    call WipeClean
    call ReadFile
    mov dx,offset filereaderline 
    mov ah,9h 
    int 21h
    call DisplayFileString
    call CloseFile 
    jmp GetCommandLetter





PrintLine:
    mov dx, offset szHelloWorld
    mov ah, 9h
    int 21h
    jmp GetCommandLetter

exit:
    mov ax, 4c00h
    int 21h
END start
```

Comment: This code is very hard to follow. Do you understand the difference between using `call` and using `jmp/je/jne`?  And what do you think is going to happen in routines (like _Error) when it hits the end of the routine?

Comment: i've changed the code,please note that the procedures i showed in the question does not longer exist since it's an older code. hope you can follow it now

Comment: So, what happens when you run it?  I assume `/h` works as expected.  But what happens when you do `/r`?  I'm guessing it prompts you for the name and lets you enter it.  It looks like it is supposed to print out the name you just entered.  Does that work?  What, exactly, are you using for the name?  And what do you think this line does `mov [byte ptr filenameStr+2+8],0`?  Specifically, what does the `8` mean?  Is OpenFile printing an error?  And that brings us to WipeClean.  You invoke it with `call`, and what happens at the end of the proc after it processes all 255 bytes?

Comment: /r reads and displayes on the screen the content of a file by writing /r "name of file", mov [byte ptr filenameStr+2+8],0 is so you could write 8 letters files in the /r command for inputing file's name,OpenFile writes Error only if the filename you gave him doesnt exist,means,only if you have a file called "help.txt", you could open it and read it's content,for the wipeClean,to be honest,i dont know why the man that helped me with the reading code added those lines,i guess to check if it worked,or if the file isnt empty

Comment: My question about /r wasn't "what is it *supposed* to do" but "what does it *currently* do"? You have never said what parts work and what doesn't. For example, if it is supposed to print out the file name you enter, does it? OpenFile should only print ErrorOpenMsg if it fails to open the file.  Does it print? I only know what you tell me, and you aren't telling me what's happening. Is "help.txt" the name of the file you are trying to open? because `mov [byte ptr filenameStr+2+8],0` won't allow "helpme.txt" to work.

Comment: Or is /r even the part you are working on?

Comment: 1st of all,I'm not working on /r since it works,im talking about a new command, i shall call it /c, it does not show about it in the full program since it's the version before i started working on /c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the DOS api you'll see that *CreateFile* and *OpenFile* are very similar functions. In your program you've successfully opened, but you fail on the creation because you made the same mistake as before when user @SepRoland helped you out. You forgot that the actual filename starts at **offset 2** in the structure that you give to DOS.

```
proc CreateFile1
    mov ah,3ch
    mov cx,00000000b
    lea dx,[filenameStr +2]             <= Add the 2 here!
    int 21h
    jc  ThisIsAnErrorOnCreatingAFile    <= Do something with the carry flag!
    mov [filehandle],ax 
    ret
endp CreateFile1
```